# Binary reader with arduino blinking 8 leds

Tags: binary, arduino, led

I´m trying to  insert a binary raw sequence `(01010100, 01101000, 01100001)` into Arduino. I would like to make 8-led group blink in a loop, showing  with light each 8-group binary sequence when: `0=light off` and `1=light on`.

It´s possible to do this operation with Arduino-Uno?

Comment: Arduino has a stackexchange channel for its own, kindly post Arduino related queries there. http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you could do something like:

```
int myPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
byte sequence[] = {B01001001,B00000001,B00000011};

void setup(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    pinMode(myPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    turnOnOff(sequence[i]);
    delay(500); //just to see results
  }
}

void turnOnOff(byte data){
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    boolean onOff = data & (B00000001 << i);
    digitalWrite(myPins[i],onOff);
  }
}
```

Comment: where should I type the binary? Pins do not output anything.

Comment: @LeCras See my update, remove the serial part so it's simpler